# Projective equivalence for quadrics and their image

Tags: projective-geometry, quadrics

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be the complex or real field and $(S_n,\mathcal{K})$ a $\mathbb{K}-$projective space of dimension $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$, where $\mathcal{K}$ is the collection of bijections $\kappa: S\to\mathbb{K}P_n$ such that $\forall\,\kappa,\kappa'\in\mathcal{K}: \kappa'\circ\kappa^{-1}\in\mathrm{Pro}_\mathbb{K}(S_n)$. In the following, given $L\in\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{K}^{n+1})$, we associate the projectivity $\omega_L: [x]\in\mathbb{K}P_n\mapsto [Lx]\in\mathbb{K}P_n$. Then, if $Q(\mathbb{K}^{n+1})$ is the vector space of quadratic forms over $\mathbb{K}^{n+1}$, we define the equivalence $\sim$ over $\mathcal{K}\times (Q(\mathbb{K}^{n+1})\setminus\{\underline{0}\})$ as $$(\kappa,q)\sim(\kappa',q')\text{ iff }\,\exists\,L\in\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{K}^{n+1})\,\exists\,\lambda\in\mathbb{K}^*\text{ such that }\kappa'=\omega_L\circ\kappa\text{ and }q'=\lambda q\circ L^{-1}$$ and then the *space of quadrics over $(S_n,\mathcal{K})$* as $$Q_\mathbb{K}(S_n):=\frac{\mathcal{K}\times (Q(\mathbb{K}^{n+1})\setminus\{\underline{0}\})}{\sim}.$$ So, given a quadric $\mathcal{Q}:=[\kappa,q]$, we call the *image of $\mathcal{Q}$* the set $$V(\mathcal{Q}):=\{P[x]_\kappa\in S\,|\, q(x)=0\}=\kappa^{-1}(\pi(C(q)\setminus\{\underline{0}\}))$$ where $C(q)$ is the isotropic cone of $q$ and $\pi:x\in\mathbb{K}^{n+1}\setminus\{\underline{0}\}\mapsto[x]\in\mathbb{K}P_n$ the canonical surjection. One definition more, given a projectivity $\Omega\in\mathrm{Pro}_\mathbb{K}(S_n)$, we can define the quadric $\Omega(\mathcal{Q}):=[\kappa\circ\Omega^{-1},q]\in Q_\mathbb{K}(S_n)$ and say that *two quadrics of $S$ are equivalent* iff exists a projectivity of $S$ that sends the first in the second. It is pretty obvious to see that if $\mathcal{Q},\mathcal{Q}'\in Q_\mathbb{K}(S_n)$ are equivalent through $\Omega\in\mathrm{Pro}_\mathbb{K}(S_n)$, that is $\mathcal{Q}'=\Omega(\mathcal{Q})$, then so are $V(\mathcal{Q})$ and $V(\mathcal{Q}')$ because one can observe that $$(P[x]_\kappa\in V(\mathcal{Q}))\iff(q(x)=0)\iff(\Omega(P)[x]_{\kappa\circ\Omega^{-1}}\in V(\mathcal{Q}'))$$ and then $V(\mathcal{Q}')=\Omega(V(\mathcal{Q}))$. Now, the question is: assuming that $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C}$, is it true that two quadrics of $S$ with same image are exactly the same quadrics? This arises if one asks if two quadrics with equivalent images are equivalent themselves: searching on those few papers available on the web, it seems that this should be true over algebraically closed fields like $\mathbb{C}$ but no one has ever provided a proof. Moreover, I've never found references about this problem on $\mathbb{R}$ even though it seems to be legit true intuitevely reasoning on conics and tridimensional quadrics. Hoping you have some satisfying answers, at least I expose my poor and incomplete attempt for the complex case. Let be $\mathcal{Q},\mathcal{Q'}$ as before, $r,r'\in\mathbb{N}^*$ their rank (that is, the rank of one of their associated quadratic forms), respectively and suppose that $V(\mathcal{Q})=V(\mathcal{Q}')$ with $r\leq r'$: we should prove that $r=r'$. (I think) I have proven that the maximum dimension of complex projective subspace included in $V(\mathcal{Q})$ is $n-\big\lfloor\frac{r+1}2\big\rfloor$ and, thanks to it, we can say that $\big\lfloor\frac{r+1}2\big\rfloor=\big\lfloor\frac{r'+1}2\big\rfloor$: recalling some basic properties of floor function, we can say that the only doubtful situation is when $r$ is odd and $\mathcal{Q}$ is degenerate ($r<n+1$) because so it has to be $r'=r$ or $r'=r+1$. I'm sure this is not the smartest way to proceed, also because I don't know how to disprove that $r'=r+1$ -- probably, I miss something about a quadrics's radical (the set of its singular points) but I cannot find among the properties I know anything useful to continue the proof. Thanks to everyone could help me, I wait for your kind opinion!